# non-variable type argument akka.actor.ActorRef

Tags: scala, akka

Here is a code involving akka:

```
def receive = {
   case idList: List[ActorRef] => idList.foreach(x => x ! Msg)
}
```

Sbt complains that:

```
non-variable type argument akka.actor.ActorRef in type pattern List[akka.actor.ActorRef] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     case idList: List[ActorRef] => idList.foreach(x => x ! Msg)
```

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At runtime `List[Whatever]` is equivalent to `List[Any]`, so your Actor can figure out that it received a list but not that it's a list of `ActorRef`s. This is a JVM thing and not Scala's or Akka's fault.

You have two choices:

1) Ignore it by replacing `ActorRef` with `_`

```
case idList: List[_] => ...
```

2) Wrap it into a datastructure (recommended)

```
case class Ids(idList: List[ActorRef])
```

The second choice let's you check against Ids without having to check for the parametric type of the list.

```
def receive = {
   case Ids(idList) => idList.foreach(x => x ! Msg)
}
```

Comment: the first choice won't compile, will it?

Comment: @MariusKavansky, I doubt the first solution will compile because you won't be able to do this any more: `idList.foreach(x => x ! Msg)` because it will no longer know that `x` is an `ActorRef`.  All the more reason to go with solution 2.

Comment: The part that I've written will definitely compile ;) but the part that I've left out won't, unless you do a cast to `ActorRef`. I'm sorry I haven't made it clear (didn't have time to clarify). It should be obvious though, that type casts exist specifically for the reason of telling the type system that you don't care about correctness ;)

Comment: It should be `case Ids(idList) => idList.foreach(x => x ! Msg)`, shouldn't it?